# Javascript IE Redirection Loop (with some PHP)

Tags: php, javascript

For some reason, the following causes a redirection loop in IE, but not in Chrome or Firefox.

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['a']) OR strlen($_POST['a'])>0)
    {
    die($_POST['a']);
    }
?>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="fpjs2.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="fbif" id="fbif" action="checkcookie.php" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="a" value="" />
</form>
<script>
var ec = new MyObject();
ec.get("fbuid", function(value) {
    document.fbif.a.value=value; 
    document.fbif.submit();
});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

The script is called checkcookie.php and it checks for the existence of a cookie (that's not the issue, don't go on about that or try to advise me on how best to do it) then posts this back to the same script. The PHP at the top should detect if something has been posted or not, if so then only display the post variable and exit (don't load the rest of the script).

On Chrome and Firefox this works perfectly. On IE it redirects endlessly. So it seems that IE is not posting the variable but only reloading itself over and over.

Comment: What is MyObject and ec.get doing?

Comment: Lots of stuff that I don't know about since I didn't write it. After some more testing I can confirm that this doesn't happen without ec.get, so that is somehow causing the problem. But it doesn't redirect if its not asked to submit the form. Additionally, even if I try to submit the form to another page, it will still refresh itself in a loop.

Comment: My best guess is that the code for that object has an ie specific bug which causes `value` to not have a value. Try `alert(value)` at the top of the function and see what its being set as in ie. If value has no value you need to fix MyObject()

Comment: If I change it to `ec.get("id", function(value) { alert("Cookie value is " + value) });` then it displays correctly in the alert. Is there a different way to post the form?

Comment: I tried just redirecting with document.location, but that doesn't work either. It doesn't want to redirect, but it is correctly retrieving the cookie.

Comment: `ec.get("id"...` is different from `ec.get("fbuid"...` which you quote in your code snippet. How about changing the `submit` statement to alert the field `value` you just set, to make sure it *is* set?

Comment: try adding an id to the input and doing `document.getElementById('inputId').value=value`

Comment: I've tried that way too, doesn't work. It won't even redirect if I change the action to another page. Just keeps reloading the same page anyway. The form is not submitted at all.

Comment: The form *is* submitted if `checkcookie.php` is executed. But either the value is not set in the form, or not sent correctly when it is submitted, or not interpreted correctly when it is received.

Comment: No, the form is not submitted at all. I changed the form action to checkcookie2.php, and this page is never loaded, regardless of the value. Only checkcookie.php is continuously refreshed. Same if I change it to `document.location="checkcookie2.php?a="+value;`. Again, the page is refreshed, but not sent to checkcookie2.php.

Comment: You are checking that IE isn't caching old versions of the page and the form target? (Sorry to ask, but best to eliminate an obvious possibility!) Perhaps you could provide a demonstrator on a server somewhere?

Comment: Certainly it's not caching, I'm checking by clearing the cache beforehand and then viewing the source to ensure its correct. This doesn't work either `location.replace("checkcookie2.php?a="+value);`. It seems that it won't redirect because it's still trying to load something else (which needs to be stopped). There must be some way to force it to redirect..?

Comment: Forcing the script to hang for 1500 milliseconds after submitting the form fixes the issue, but that is not an elegant solution by any means.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion you were right that on IE it doesn't post "a" variable, but it should make post of the form. So I bet the issue is on your javascript and compatibility with IE.

I would try to not posting the form, but trying to check if it returns value you think it should return, mby with `alert(value);` or just commenting submit function and checking if input got the value.

EDIT: `isset($_POST['a']) OR strlen($_POST['a'])>0` => `isset($_POST['a'])` totally same effect as if strlen($_POST['a'])>0 would be true, then isset($_POST['a']) also would be true.

Comment: Those do not have the same effect. This would, however: `if (empty($_POST['a']))`.